# Why doesn't my custom object Java HashMap handle unique keys?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

Below code returns false. Trying to make Equation object act as a key in a custom HashMap. Pretty sure method overrides are implemented correctly, hashCode is the exact same between the two equation instances. What is exactly wrong?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean maxPoints(int[][] points) {
        Map<Equation, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        Equation eq1 = new Equation(1, 2);
        Equation eq2 = new Equation(1, 2);
        map.put(eq1, 1);
        if (map.containsKey(eq1)) return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    class Equation {
        private int slope;
        private int yIntercept;
        public Equation(int slope, int yIntercept) {
            this.slope = slope;
            this.yIntercept = yIntercept;
        }
        
        public boolean equals(Equation other) {
            if (other == this) return true;
            return (this.slope == other.slope && this.yIntercept == other.yIntercept);
        }
        
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.slope, this.yIntercept);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a correct way to override `Object.equals()`. It will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

`equals` needs to be `public boolean equals(Object other)` to match the signature in `Object`.

Your `equals` method doesn't override the one that the code in `HashMap` is calling.

Usually an `equals` method looks like this:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof Equation)) {
        return false;
    }
    // instanceof above also covers null
    Equation otherEquation = (Equation) other;
    return otherEquation.slope == this.slope
        && otherEquation.yIntercept == this.yIntercept;
}
```

...or use [Project Lombok's](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite a method annotade it with `@Override`.
The compiler would give you an error for your `equals` because you do not overwrite but overload the method

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    ...
}
```